# What does "Kollegen" mean exactly?

Tags: translation

I think "Kollegen" means only the male colleagues. Or does it mean the female colleagues, or even both?

I can't find an explanation in the dictionaries.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called "generisches Maskulinum". It is explained here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum and here: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=&v_id=3286

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Kollege** is the male form while female would be **Kollegin** - but a lot of people just say **meine Kollegen** if they're referring to both (where **meine Kolleginnen und Kollegen** or **das Kollegium** would be the better form).

So in conclusion:

- **Kollegen** = *may* mean both genders, depending on the context (plural)
- **Kollege** = male (singular)
- **Kolleginnen**/**Kollegin** = female (plural/singular)
- **Kollegium** = both, including yourself (plural) - used mainly in the context of schools, not for general work Kollegen.

Comment: "Es ist nicht so eine schlechte Idee, kollegen auf Facebook zu haben" - this is the context. Thank you for answering this in english :)

Comment: So was I right when I wrote to a male collegaue in the previous context?

Comment: yes, thats ok (if you're meaning both genders, otherwise you should be more explicit to exclude women). to make that sentence sound a little better, you could've written `Es ist keine schlechte Idee` or `Es ist nicht schlecht` instead of `Es ist nicht so eine schlechte Idee` because `nicht so eine` sounds a little curious - but thats just peanuts.

Comment: @LanceBaynes *Kollege* is a noun, pay attention on the upper case. In your context *Kollegen* will be understand as plural for both male and female colleagues.

Comment: @oezi: If you work at a school, then _Kollegium_ is good. If you use this word for your _Kollegen_ at a company, you'd receive some curious looks, I guess.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, "Kollegium" ist für mich ziemlich eingeschränkt, auf die Menge der *Lehrer an einer Schule*. Für andere Arbeitsbereiche würde ich das nicht benutzen.

Comment: @HendrikVogt [Kollegium: Gruppe von Personen mit gleichem Amt oder Beruf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kollegium). Best example and most used for Teachers. But it isn't wrong to broaden it to other contexts.

Comment: Von einem Freund aus der Schweiz kenne ich das Wort `Kollege` auch im Kontext von `Freund`. Allerdings bin ich nicht sicher, ob dies generell im Schweizerischen so verwendet wird.

Comment: Note that, like with anything else, the male form in general is also the gender-neutral form, even if used in singular. If I say "Das erledigt ein Kollege von mir", it may very well be a female co-worker. The long form "meine Kolleginnen und Kollegen" is only required in very politically correct contexts. "Liebe Mitgliederinnen und Mitglieder" is an exaggerated joke of always having female words when the male word would suffice. And also note that a lof of immigrants I know use the term "Kollege" when referring to "Freund", likely because their native language has a similar word.

Comment: @Em1: It may not be _wrong_, but as I wrote - be prepared for curious looks. People just don't use it in other contexts (at least not the people I know). EDIT: I don't like the general description "Gruppe von Personen mit gleichem Amt oder Beruf"; it's misleading. But the example "ein Kollegium von Ärztinnen und Ärzten" seems to be good - for medical doctors, _Kollegium_ is apparently not uncommon. (I didn't know that.)

Comment: @Geziefer *Kollege* as *Freund* or more likely as *guter Bekannter* is usual.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt Dann konstruiere mal ein Kollegium aus einem Chefarzt, ein paar Oberärzten und diversen Assistenzärzten.

Comment: @bernd_k: Ich habe keine Ahnung, wie _Kollegium_ bei Ärzten gebraucht wird. (Note my "I didn't know that.")

Comment: In youth language, it is used like "Alter" or mate/pal as well. "Ey Kollege" is commonly used to get someone's attention. This might be regional though. In addition, in slang the plural is often changed to "Kollegas". This is by no means proper German, just some additional perspective.

Comment: I assume that "Kollegium ... (plural)" means only that the word refers to several colleagues, not that it counts as a plural noun and would therefore take a plural verb.